# Size of Elasticsearch query from Apollo GraphQL client is always ten

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using GraphQL for my backend to frontend communication and Elasticsearch as my DB. The problem is that whenever I call a query from the frontend, the size is always ten in spite of me specifying in the query the size as 1000. This behaviour is occurring when I am using the GraphQL playground which returns the correct number of hits.

My ES search request is:

```
async rangeSessions(_, args) {
  const { dateFrom, dateTo } = args;      

  const results = await client.search({
    index: 'logs-cdigm',
    size: 1000,
    body: {
      aggs: {
        sessions: {
          terms: {
            field: 'session_id.keyword',
            size: 1000
          },
          aggs: {
            start_time: { min: { field: 'ts' } },
            end_time: { max: { field: 'ts' } },
            events_count: { value_count: { field: 'sequence_id' } },
          },
        },
      },
      query: {
        range: {
          timestamp: {
            lte: dateTo * 1000000,
            gt: dateFrom * 1000000,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const res = [];    
  console.log(results.body.aggregations.sessions.buckets.length);

  results.body.aggregations.sessions.buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
    res.push({
      session_id: bucket.key,
      events_count: bucket.doc_count,
      start_time: bucket.start_time.value_as_string,
      end_time: bucket.end_time.value_as_string,
    });
  });

  return res;
}
```

My GraphQL query is:

```
query sessionSearch ($from: Float!, $to: Float!) {
  rangeSessions(dateFrom: $from, dateTo: $to) {
    session_id
    start_time
    end_time
    events_count
  }
}
```

My request is:

```
// from frontend
{"operationName":"sessionSearch","variables":{"from":1567555200000,"to":1567728000000},"query":"query sessionSearch($from: Float!, $to: Float!) {\n  rangeSessions(dateFrom: $from, dateTo: $to) {\n    session_id\n    start_time\n    end_time\n    events_count\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}


{
  body: null,
  statusCode: null,
  headers: null,
  warnings: null,
  meta: {
   context: null,
    request: { params: [Object], options: [Object], id: 2 },
    name: 'elasticsearch-js',
    connection: {
      url: 'http://localhost:9200/',
      id: 'http://localhost:9200/',
      headers: {},
      deadCount: 0,
      resurrectTimeout: 0,
      _openRequests: 0,
      status: 'alive',
      roles: [Object]
    },
    attempts: 0,
    aborted: false
  }
}

// request object
{
  params: {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/logs-cdigm/_search',
    body: '{"aggs":{"sessions":{"terms":{"field":"session_id.keyword","size":1000},"aggs":{"start_time":{"min":{"field":"ts"}},"end_time":{"max":{"field":"ts"}},"events_count":{"value_count":{"field":"sequence_id"}}}}},"query":{"range":{"timestamp":{"lte":1567728000000000000,"gt":1567555200000000000}}}}',
    querystring: 'size=1000',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'elasticsearch-js/7.3.0 (linux 4.15.0-64-generic-x64; Node.js v12.10.0)',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': '293'
    }
  },
  options: { warnings: null },
  id: 2
}
```

How do I get more than 10 results in my frontend?

Comment: First off, since you're interested in aggregations only, you should set `size: 0` instead of `size: 1000` in your search query. The only size that counts is the one in your terms aggregation. Then it's not clear what the `res` variable may contain in your return statement as it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: @Val I had put the size of the search query as 0 initially. I was just trying it out in case this worked. I have also updated my code with `res`.

Comment: Can you [listen to the `request` event](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/observability.html#_events) and print out the actual request that gets sent?

Comment: Thanks, can you now run that raw query directly in Dev Tools or curl and see how many buckets you get?

Comment: @Val I am getting 10 buckets.

Comment: Ok, are you sure that you have more than 10 different values for `session_id`?

Comment: @Val Yes, I am sure. They are coming when I send the request from GraphQL Playground.

Comment: Are you sure you're counting the number of terms buckets and not the number of hits (just making sure we're talking about the same thing)?

Comment: @Val Yes, it is the number of buckets.

Comment: Intriguing... it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch number of results by default is 10.
You need to specify how many results (there is a Max:10k I believe?)

The place of the size is important, it should be in the **body** of your request:

See here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size

Comment: Did you read the question? The size is already specified. It is only returning ten from the frontend, not in other cases.